# WPF - Exclude element from scrollbar effect in one way

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, scrollviewer

Is there any way to exclude certain `UIElement` from a certain scroll effect? I have a grid element below a columns header element. while I'd like to have full scrolling over the grid, I want the header to be affected only by the horizontal scrolling. so that it will always stay at the top when scrolling down.

Here is a mspaint I made to explain in case my explenation didn't make sense.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not move your scroll viewer inside the green rows and then have a different scroll viewer for the header.

Then wrap it all in a parent container

So like

```
<Grid>   
   <HeaderControl>
     <ScrollViewer />
   </HeaderControl>
   <BodyControl>
     <ScrollViewer />
   </BodyContent>
</Grid>
```

Wrapping them together in one scroll viewer is overly complicated. Splitting it into two distinct scroll viewers will simplify the problem IMO.

Comment: This is some nice idea, I must hide the bars of the header and then sync between the horizontal scroll.  if it will work, Ill give you the V, good sir.

Comment: Sure, you can hide the horizontal scroll bar in the header control and then bind the horizontal scroll position to the body scroll viewers horizontal scroll position

Comment: It works really well, but one problem. once you get to the edge, the aligment between the header and the grid gets distorted because of the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Solved the problem by leaving the vertical bar of the header visible. it's not pretty, but not too ugly either, and in overal it all works good now, thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used 2 separate scroll viewers - an outer one that contains both the header and the grid, and that only handles the horizontal scrolling.

Then the grid itself can be wrapped in a separate scroll viewer that handles just the vertical scrolling on of the grid. E.g:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">  
   <!-- Header -->
   <Grid>
   </Grid>
   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
      <!-- Content -->
      <Grid>
      </Grid>
   <ScrollViewer />
</Grid>
```

Although I'm not 100% sure about the two visibility settings - you might have to play around with them to see what works

Comment: That will work, but the problem is that then one of the scroll bars may be out of the view. for instance if the grid is wider then the screen, then you will have to scroll to the side to see the the vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Ah, yes, hadn't thought of that - that makes it a bit trickier if you need to see both scroll bars at all times. Will have to have another think...

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to do the same. My solution would be using a Canvas for the header and Scrollviewer for the body.

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=ValueScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset, Converter={StaticResource DoubleMultiplyingConverter}, ConverterParameter=-1}">
       Header
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
<ScrollViewer Name="ValueScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <Grid>
        Table
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

With converter:

```
public class DoubleMultiplyingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var factor = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var val = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
        return val * factor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To handle all the situations, you should separate static part (header) and scrollable part (body) and wrap body with `ScrollViewer`. This solution is perfect in everything, except the situation when your control is wider than screen (or outer control), so horizontal scroll should be allowed too and header should be also scrolled. You can't just use inner scrollviwer for this, because vertical scrollbar will only be visible when horizontal scroll is at right edge.

You can't exclude header from only vertical scroll, but you can simulate horizontal one. You can do it with just translation transform.

```
<Grid>
  <!-- body part. place it first to make it go to the background -->
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="scrollbar">
    <!-- the body control itself -->
    <Canvas x:Name="PART_Body"/>
  </ScrollViewer>

  <!-- header part. Border and margin are used to make it not overlap vertical scrollbar -->
  <Border Margin="0,0,18,18" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Canvas x:Name="PART_Header">
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <!-- bind X to the scrollbar X position -->
        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=scrollbar, Path=ContentHorizontalOffset, Converter={StaticResource InvertDoubleConverter}}"/>
        <!-- InvertDoubleConverter is just a value converter which multiples incmoing double value by -1 -->
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      </Canvas>
  </Border>
</Grid>
```